animation based on view-timeline for different element
I'm trying to animate an Element B based on a view-timeline property set on element A. With view-timeline it's possible to invoke animations based on an element's position in the viewport if the view-timeline is then set on animation-timeline.
MDN states explicitly:

The name is then referenced in an animation-timeline declaration to indicate the element that will be animated as the timeline progresses. This can be the subject element, but it doesn't have to be — you can animate a different element as the subject moves through the scrolling area.

So it should be possible to animate an element B (let's say by rotating it or change it's background color) by setting the animation-timeline of this element to the view-timeline of another element A (subject):


.container {
    min-height: 200vh;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    right: 50px;
    top: 50px;
}

.square {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
}

#A {
   background-color: green;
    margin-top: 50%;
    view-timeline: --aTimeline y;
}

#B {
    background-color: red;
    animation-timeline: --aTimeline;
    animation-name: slideInFixedSquare;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-duration: 1ms; 
}

@keyframes slideInFixedSquare {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scaleX(0);
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }
}
<!-- does not work -->
<div class="container">
  <div id="A" class="square"></div>
  <div id="B" class="square fixed"></div>
</div>

<!-- does work -->
<div class="container">
  <div id="A" class="square">
     <div id="B" class="square fixed"></div>
  </div>
</div>



The animation on B seems to work only if B is a descendant of A, although that is not explicitly stated in the documentation (MDN). Does anyone know a way to make this animation work even if B is not descendant of A?

It's a scoping issue. You have to face this at least once when working with scroll-driven animations.
Make sure you have timeline-scope: --rotateFixedSquare; on a parent element of #B otherwise it's by default limited to #A and its descendant.


.container {
  min-height: 200vh;
  timeline-scope: --rotateFixedSquare;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  right: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}

.square {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#A {
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 50%;
  view-timeline: --rotateFixedSquare y;
}

#B {
  background-color: red;
  animation-timeline: --rotateFixedSquare;
  animation-name: appear;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-duration: 1ms;
}

@keyframes appear {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <div id="A" class="square"></div>
  <div id="B" class="square fixed"></div>
</div>



